# Python 3 minimum and maximum built-in function

Tags: python-3.x, python-2.x, minimum, built-in

would like to know what is the objective of update the built-in function from Python2 to Python 3, below is the code

```
# Python 2
list1 = [123, 'xyz', 'zara', 'abc']
list2 = [456, 700, 200]
print " Minimum of list 1 is : ", min(list1)  #answer is 123
print " Minimum of list 2 is : ", min(list2)  #answer is 200

#python 3
print ("Minimum of list 1 is : "), min(list1)

##----- TypeError: unorderable types: str() < int()
```

So, may i know how to address this problem in Python 3 and the objective to improve the built-in function. Thanks in advace for any advice and suggestion. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is nothing to improve.

`min` and `max` just do `123 < "xyz"`.

In Python2 `int` is always less than `str`. In Python3 it's actually *fixed*, they are incomparable now (because there is *actually* no way to compare 42 and "dog" you know).

In your case I recommend to use [filter](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#filter) to find the minimum among the values you actually want.